# unable to focus on small text in android

Tags: android, camera, barcode

I am making an app for reading small text but i am not able to get `sharp focus` . i am using `SCENE_MODE_BARCODE` for scene mode for small text but it seems to be not working i tried `autofocus` also but no result either.
sorry for bad english.
my preview class code is

```
public class MyView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
Camera surfacecmr;
SurfaceHolder mholder;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public MyView(Context context, Camera cmr) {
    super(context);
    surfacecmr = cmr;
    mholder = getHolder();
    mholder.addCallback(this);
    mholder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        // surfacecmr.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        surfacecmr.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        surfacecmr.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    if (mholder.getSurface() == null)
        return;

    surfacecmr.stopPreview();
    // get Camera parameters
    Camera.Parameters params = surfacecmr.getParameters();

    params.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_BARCODE);

    surfacecmr.setParameters(params);

    try {
        surfacecmr.setPreviewDisplay(mholder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    surfacecmr.startPreview();

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    surfacecmr.release();
}

}
```